# R data-frame: Inter-row calculations

Tags: r, time-series

This is an extension of [Subtract previous year's from value from each grouped row in data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9552771/subtract-previous-years-from-value-from-each-grouped-row-in-data-frame). The option using plyr makes complete sense.

Now, I'm trying to add a couple more columns. I've also modified year so it's an actual year with different starting points by id. Here is a link to tab-delimited df: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/9699533/df.txt

[image]

I am unable to get a pointer to the previous row when I'm in the current row. I'd like to pass this to the function part of plyr::transform. How do I write this, please? Thanks!

~*~*~*~* Alternate dataframe input ~*~*~*~*~

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L), value = c(6L, 16L, 21L, 5L, 10L, 26L, 2L, 
12L, 26L, 9L, 16L, 26L, 2L, 15L, 29L), year = c(2007L, 2008L, 
2009L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2004L, 2004L, 2006L, 2010L, 2011L, 
2012L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L), actual = c(6L, 10L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
16L, 2L, 10L, 14L, 9L, 7L, 10L, 2L, 13L, 14L)), .Names = c("id", 
"value", "year", "actual"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-15L))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `transform`.

```
foo <- function(x){
   x$ratio <- c(NA,tail(x$actual,-1)/head(x$value,-1))
   x
 }
> 
> ddply(df,.(id),foo)
   id value year actual     ratio
1   1     6 2007      6        NA
2   1    16 2008     10 1.6666667
3   1    21 2009      5 0.3125000
4   2     5 2011      5        NA
5   2    10 2012      5 1.0000000
6   2    26 2013     16 1.6000000
7   3     2 2004      2        NA
8   3    12 2004     10 5.0000000
9   3    26 2006     14 1.1666667
10  4     9 2010      9        NA
11  4    16 2011      7 0.7777778
12  4    26 2012     10 0.6250000
13  5     2 2014      2        NA
14  5    15 2015     13 6.5000000
15  5    29 2016     14 0.9333333
```

If we can assume your data frame is sorted, and that we know how big each group (by `id`) is, we don't even need to do the whole split-apply thing:

```
df$ratio2 <- with(df,c(NA,tail(actual,-1) / head(value,-1)))
df$ratio2[seq(1,nrow(df),by = 3)] <- NA
```

Comment: Thanks, Joran. The groups may be of unequal size. So, I'll stick with ddply. How about the seq column? The set is ordered.

Comment: Put `x$seq <- seq_along(x$id) - 1` in `foo` as well?