# Calculate duration/difference between first and n rows that match on column value

Tags: r, dplyr, duration

I'm trying to calculate difference/duration between the first and *n* rows of a dataframe that match in one column. I want to place that value in a new column "duration". Sample data: below.

```
y <- data.frame(c("USA", "USA", "USA", "France", "France", "Mexico", "Mexico", "Mexico"), c(1992, 1993, 1994, 1989, 1990, 1999, 2000, 2001))
colnames(y) <- c("Country", "Year")
y$Year <- as.integer(y$Year) # this is to match the class of my actual data
```

My desired result is:

```
1992    USA 0
1993    USA 1
1994    USA 2
1989    France  0
1990    France  1
1999    Mexico  0
2000    Mexico  1
2001    Mexico  2
```

I've tried using [dplyr's group_by and mutate](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25889/lagging-over-a-grouped-time-series)

```
y <- y %>% group_by(Country) %>% mutate(duration = Year - lag(Year))
```

but I can only get the actual lag year (e.g. 1999) or only calculate the difference between sequential rows getting me either *NA* for the first row of a country or 1 for all other rows with the same country. [Many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36989976/conditionally-calculate-time-differences-between-rows-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1) [q & a's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15505879/date-time-differences-between-rows-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1) focus on [difference between sequential rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9552771/subtract-previous-years-from-value-from-each-grouped-row-in-data-frame) and not between the first and *n* rows.

Thoughts?

Comment: You can do this `with(y, ave(seq_along(Year), Country, FUN = seq_along)-1)` or if it is the difference `y %>% group_by(Country) %>% mutate(duration = Year - first(Year))`

Comment: Thanks, @akrun! This is great. I'm new-ish to R and spent a few hours trying to figure it out but must have been searching for the wrong terms/processes. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by subtracting the `first` 'Year' with the 'Year' column after grouping by 'Country'.

```
y %>%
   group_by(Country) %>%
   mutate(duration = Year - first(Year))
```